# iptables: forwarding ssh ports

Tags: iptables

I have a server with two NICs:
eth4 - listens on the outside network.
eth1 - is on the same network as machine Y.

I want to be able to ssh into machine Y by doing: `ssh server -p 1234` from the outside network.

I've come up with the following rules:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth4 -t nat -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DNAT --to-destination $MACHINE_Y_IP:22`

and

`iptables -A FORWARD -i eth4 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

When I try to ssh, the connection is not refused right away, but it feels like iptables are not forwarding packets back. Any clue as to what I might doing wrong? OS is SLES, if that matters for the syntax.

Edit:
`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` reports `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

`iptables-save` generate:

```
`# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.2-rc1 on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [48787:5748712]
:INPUT ACCEPT [48725:5742333]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [29:1740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [25938:4009532]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [25967:4011272]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.2-rc1 on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [68959:12817029]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [19579:1207747]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [19566:1206967]
-A PREROUTING -i eth4 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DNAT --to-destination x.x.x.x:22 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.2-rc1 on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [60982622:59727981305]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [10:600]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [32438834:64059260511]
-A FORWARD -i eth4 -o eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Nov 12 10:28:26 2010`
```

Comment: What does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` say? What is the complete output from `iptables-save`?

Comment: Steven, sorry, not enough space, will edit the answer in a second to add more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rules should look something like this.

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth4 --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to server:22
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth4 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Don't bother mixing in the state module. It is most likely what causes your problems. The NAT module will keep the states you need.

Oh, make sure you have ip_forwarding turned on also ;)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for me, I wonder if I am missing something in SLES setup, firewall is off, but I did do `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. Also, should not --dport in FORWARD be 22?

Comment: You are correct, typo on my part. The forward rule should go to port 22.

Comment: +1. One little quibble though: The ACCEPT rule on the FORWARD chain is redundant, since the policy on the FORWARD chain is already to ACCEPT. Oh, and the `--to` really should be `--to-destination`.

Comment: I see what my problem might be. When I do `ssh -v MACHINE_Y -p 1234`, wireshark listening on eth1 one shows that there are packets coming from the eth4 ip address, to the ip address of the box I am trying to ssh into (it's on eth1 network). So it feels like I need a SNAT rule that will change the eth4 ip address to eth1 ip address, no?

Comment: added this: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth1 --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source x.x.x.x`, where `x.x.x.x` is eth1's ip address and it seems to work now. Praise to you guys for the direction and WireShark, I was slowly going insane. :)

Comment: My VM inside a Server and i want to ssh to it how can i do it, will this work for me ? My Base Server machine has been bridged now the bridge was vmbr0 and there was another bridge for vms was vmbr1, if im ssh to the public ip of this server it want to forward the ssh to the vms ssh how can it do it in iptables

Comment: @StevenMonday Not only that it is redundant, but confusing. I have REJECT as my default on FORWARD, thus needed additional entries there. Took me a while to figure out that the FORWARD-rule provided here does not suffice, but you need a rule to accept the other direction as well (`-i eth1 -o eth4 -j ACCEPT`, if you want with state established)

Comment: Why do you need the FORWARD rule? The manpage for DNAT says "It specifies that the destination address of the packet should be modified (and all future packets in this connection will also be mangled), and rules should cease being examined.". Does this not mean that whatever is in the FORWARD chain or any other chain will be ignored ("cease being examined")?

Answer (score 1):

Below are my working rules - but I use state module:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [101:9081]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [89:5340]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [209:13346]

# DNAT to local ip
#-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport $FW_EXTERNAL_PORT -d $FW_EXTERNAL_IP -j DNAT --to-destination $INTERNAL_MACHINE_IP:$INTERNAL_MACHINE_PORT

# ssh to server 192.168.0.3
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -d 10.10.10.10 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.3:22
...
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5583:2021142]
:FORWARD DROP [24:2378]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6291:2229990]

#rules for DNAT
#-A FORWARD -p tcp --dport $INTERNAL_MACHINE_PORT -d $INTERNAL_MACHINE_IP -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# SSH to 192.168.0.3
-A FORWARD -p tcp --sport 22 -s 192.168.0.3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.0.3 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
... 
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope there is more to your iptables configuration than what you're showing us.
In the *filter table, INPUT is set to accept by default.  For people that are new to iptables, they may take that and run with it and leave their system exposed.  You may want to set the default chains in filter to DROP then only open the ports you want to get to your box, otherwise you would have a "chain-link fence" instead of a firewall.
With your POSTROUTING rule, it would work but you would have to create a similar rule for each port opened. Something like this [iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth4 -j SNAT --to pu.bl.ic.ip] would work for all ports going to the external interface.
In the FORWARD chain it is a good idea to use "belt and suspenders" to protect your box. You can add -s yo.ur.ext.ip so if anyone else tries to access on that port, they will be dropped.  I hope this helps someone.